# voltage controled router

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, component-selection

In many occasions, it is desired to design a circuit that would work under a wide range of input voltages, e.g. 3V-40V. This turns out to be annoying and difficult. I come to understand that all what is needed is a IC that acts as a voltage dependent router: ideally, it would have a ground and input pins G and I, and two or more other pins, e.g. O1, O2, O3 etc., with corresponding dedicated voltages V1, V2, V3 etc., such that if the voltage between G and I is between Vi-1 and Vi, then the IC would direct the input current via pin Oi (other pins off). This would allow to build a separate circuit for each voltage range. I guess that it is possible to do something like this with a microcontroller, but is there an IC that perform this task?

Comment: Whats the working voltage of your circuit? Whats the application?
You need a switched power supply.

Comment: I could explain why I need this presently, and there probably exists a specific solution. But I just don't want to do that: the aim of the question is precisely to know if there exists a generic tool that perform this kind of task. Actually, I was several time faced with the same problem, with different applications.

Comment: If you need a stable voltage output under a larger range input voltage. You just need a regulating power supply. If the voltage desired is higher then the lowest input voltage you need (or more efficiency is required) a (boost) switching power supply.

The more information you give the better the answers. I asked for circuit specifics. The application does not need to be specific.

Comment: Let me give an example: to design a soft start circuit that would accept DC input from 3V to 40V, deliver a gradually increasing current for 0.5s, and then activate a 15A switch to allow the full power flowing. Of course, the circuit should consume as less power as possible.

Comment: Google "buck-boost converter".

Comment: Of course, I know them but this is not the point.

Comment: A lot of manufacturers make 'soft' start DC/DC converters and will ramp or delay start. We don't do product recommendations here, because we don't like being the middleman but you are more then welcome to google.

Comment: laptop2d: and YOU are welcome to answer the question, if you can, and not another question deduced from an example given in comments. Regarding your last observation, even the Art of Electronics gives recommendations for standard components. I have edited the question and erased the word "cheap" though.

Comment: Look into "window comparators", and have each one drive a range switch

Comment: Sam, your answer is excellent, why not write it as an "official" answer ? There is also a very suitable web page at http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/window_comparator.htm

Comment: Laptop2d, Brhans etc. (domino effect). My question is perfectly clear, and was very well understood by Theamk and Sam. It's my right to ask a question regarding a tool performing a generic task, without having to specify a specific circuit.  I've got the answer to my question: there is no IC that perform this task, but a circuit known as "Window comparator" offers a good replacement. You are free to leave much more stupid questions and to remove this one: I WILL NOT REEDIT THIS QUESTION THAT IS WELL POSED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pre-defined tool for that, and moreover, microcontroller is likely going to be overkill there. From what you are describing, it looks like you want a combination of two stages:

- Input stage -- a block of voltage comparators -- they compare input voltage to a number of pre-set voltages and output digital signal (on/off).

  - This is usually done with a number of discrete comparator elements, here is an example using a quad comparator:
    http://www.electroschematics.com/6956/led-dc-voltage-indicator/
  - For the some specific cases, for example when you have 10 evenly-spaced voltage levels, you can use chips designed to drive volume meters:
    http://www.usbekits.com/blog--news/january-14th-2013
  - I suppose you could use microcontroller ADC if you really have a lot of inputs, but then you need to worry about powering it, programming it and sanitizing input signal. A lot of time a single LM339 is just easier.
- Output stage.

  - The individual comparators will give you more than one active bit (so output will be 0000, 0001, 0011, 0111, etc...) If you have lots of outputs, you can fix this with "priority encoder" chip, followed by regular decoder. If you only have few outputs, you can can fix this with some discrete logic, or by arranging the output stage so this is not a problem.
  - You say "then the IC would direct the input current via pin Oi (other pins off)". This is the weirdest requirement. Why would you want to direct "input" somewhere?  For example, if you want to control relay, you want to amplify comparator output and connect it to relay. If you want to have a soft-start circuit, you will likely have R-C circuit which will be controlled by a transistor connected to digital comparator output.
  - If you want to switch weak analog signals, you can use an IC called "analog CMOS switch", such as CD4066. For higher power, you will have to rig your own switch from relays or mosfets with appropriate drivers.

Comment: Indeed, several LM339 will probably often do for the 2-40V range (thx). Regarding the "direction of the input", the "weird" idea was simply to allow to have a separate circuit for each voltage sub-range. If you know that the input voltage is 5-10V, it is easy to design a circuit that do what you want. And similarly if you know that it is 10-20V. But it is harder to design a circuit that will do if the input range is 5-20V (say). Hence this idea of "input routing".